# What is the min and max value for 'n' in CHARACTER(n), CHARACTER VARYING(n) and TEXT datatype while creating a table in Postgres?

Tags: sql, postgresql

```
create table abc(name character(n), name1 character varying(n), name2 text);
```

In the above query what is the limit of 'n'?

```
create table abc(name character(), name1 character varying(), name2 text);
```

In the above query what it will take if we not specify any value to 'n'?

Answer (score -1, accepted):

While creating table the limit of 'n' for CHARACTER and CHARACTER VARYING datatype is,

```
                           MIN        MAX 
CHARACTER(n)          -->    1    to   10485760 characters(not bytes)
CHARACTER VARYING(n)  -->    1    to   10485760 characters(not bytes)
```

- character() if you do not specify the length it take default as character(1) when you create the table, but you can leave the column values empty.
- character varying() if you do not specify the length it will create the column with no errors, you can insert values from 0 to 10485760 characters to the column.
- For `text` datatype you cannot specify the length, you can insert values from 0 to 10485760 characters to the column.

Comment: This is just simply not true for PostgreSQL

Comment: @pozs thank you for your comment.Please refer the updated answer i am happy to hear your reviews.

Comment: PostgreSQL [has no such restriction](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/datatype-character.html), still. These types has only storage limitations, but because it can use UTF-8 (and use it by default), which has a variable-length character representation, they have literally no maximum characters they can store.

Comment: There is a limit of 10485760 characters for `n` in `varchar(n)`, see [Size limit of character varying Postgresql.](https://dba.stackexchange.com/a/189895/38456) The rest of the answer is obviously incorrect, read [the documentation.](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/datatype-character.html)

Answer (score 2):

[Quote from the manual](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/datatype-character.html)

> The notations `varchar(n)` and `char(n)` are aliases for `character varying(n)` and `character(n)`, respectively. `character` without length specifier is equivalent to `character(1)`. If `character varying` is used without length specifier, the type accepts strings of any size.

and further down:

> In any case, the longest possible character string that can be stored is about 1 GB